# How to make a text-based program into a GUI? Would tkinter be the key?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am finishing up on my first Python project. It is a text-based program converting metric and standard units. What could I use to turn the program into a GUI program. I have looked into tkinter. However, I am not sure if this would be the best solution for my situation. I would appreciate a little guidance as I am really new to programming.

Comment: all GUIs work different then normal console programs. If you use it as `script.py arguments` then you may use `Button` in GUI to run it with `subprocess` and get result and display in `Label`. But if you use `input()` then you will have to rewrite all code and use GUI widgets. It could be good to keep code in function which gets only values (without using `input()`) because then you could import it and use without using `subprocess`

Comment: Yes - TKinter would be good for this. You just need a form with two input fields (metric \ standard) and a convert button.

Comment: `tkinter` can used to do what you want, however it's very poorly documented — although there a many third-party tutorials that cover it.

Answer (score 1):

It is good if you have code in functions which get value and return result - without using `input()` and `print()`

```
def inch_to_cm(value):
     return value * 2.54
```

because then you can use it in text-base program (console program) using `input()`

```
value = input('inch: ')

value = int(value)
result = inch_to_cm(value)
print(result)
```

or using arguments in command line `script.py arguments`

```
value = sys.argv[1]

value = int(value)
result = inch_to_cm(value)
print(result)
```

or you can easily import to any GUI (`Tkinter`, `PyQT`, `PyGTK`, `Kivy`, etc.)

```
import tkinter as tk
import script  # <-- import your function

def convert():
    value = inch_entry.get()
    value = int(value)
    result = script.inch_to_cm(value)  # <-- use your function
    cm_result['text'] = result
    
root = tk.Tk()

inch_label = tk.Label(root, text='inch:')
inch_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
                 
inch_entry = tk.Entry(root)
inch_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

cm_label = tk.Label(root, text='cm:')
cm_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
                 
cm_result = tk.Label(root)
cm_result.grid(row=1, column=1)

button = tk.Button(root, text='Convert', command=convert)
button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()  # it starts program
```

I assumed that file `script.py` is like

```
import sys

def inch_to_cm(value):
     return value * 2.54
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        value = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        value = input('inch: ')

    value = int(value)
    result = inch_to_cm(value)
    print(result)
```

It needs `if __name__ == '__main__'` to run some code only when it is executed directly but not when it is imported to other program.

---

If you don't have code in functions but you can run it as `script.py argument` then you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to run it and get result

```
 result = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'script.py', value])
```

This way you can use different programs with almost the same GUI

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

def convert():
    value = inch_entry.get()
    result = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'script.py', value])
    cm_result['text'] = result.strip()
    
root = tk.Tk()

inch_label = tk.Label(root, text='inch:')
inch_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
                 
inch_entry = tk.Entry(root)
inch_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

cm_label = tk.Label(root, text='cm:')
cm_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
                 
cm_result = tk.Label(root)
cm_result.grid(row=1, column=1)

button = tk.Button(root, text='Convert', command=convert)
button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()  # it starts program and display window
```

---

If you use standard module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to get arguments in command line then there is module to generate GUI -
[Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey)

---

If your code use `input()` to get data then it can make bigger problem and you may need use other functions in `subprocess` to send text to `input()` ot it may need [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) to works with this type of program.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinker is a simple and easy way to add GUI to your program and you actually can create some good looking interfaces, so If I were you I would use Tkinter.